# Confusing output with SIPp remote commands through C++'s system() on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, centos, sip

I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding how the system() command is functioning on Ubuntu.

I am creating a C++ program to remotely control SIPp clients ([SIPp remotely controlling clients](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Remote+control))  and have pretty much completed the program, but I'm now running into an issue when I'm testing it.

I had already tested this on my centOS VM, and it was running perfectly, but now that I'm testing it on my Ubuntu VM, it's failing to even execute the commands.

On Ubuntu's terminal, I can run `echo + >/dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8888` and the SIPp client will accept the command, However, when I run my program (Which does the same thing) I get a `sh: 1: cannot create /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8888: Directory nonexistent`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    system("echo + >/dev/udp/127.0.0.1/8888");
    return 0;//
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine on centOS and the SIPp client recieves and performs the task, but on Ubuntu it's giving me the Directory nonexistent error.

From what I can see, it's currently trying to read the > as me attempting me to output a file, but escaping the > with \> just produces a compiler error.

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\>' [enabled by default]
 system("echo + \>");
        ^
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be one happy camper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching around forever I realized it was because access to /dev/udp was a bash only function, and system() was interpreted by bin/sh.

Changing my system() call to `system("bash -c \"echo + >/dev/udp/localhost/8888\"");` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar Problem and found a different  solution, i had to do it in a bashscript and ubuntu threw the same error. This worked for me:

```
echo "+" | nc -4u -w1 127.0.0.1 8888
```

Got it from here: http://mikeberggren.com/post/53883822425/ncudp